# Fade image in and out on Jquery hover

Tags: jquery, image, hover

I am using a very basic jquery script to show an image on hover (as shown below):

HTML:

```
<li>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="drag"></div> (display:none in css)
    </div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="drag"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

....many more list items with same format.
The Jquery Is:

```
$(".block").hover(function(){
      $(this).find(".drag").stop().fadeIn(250);                
  }, function(){
      $(this).find(".drag").stop().fadeOut(250);
});
```

Although this works, it is not working VERY well. Randomly, some `.block` divs don't show the image, and some don't fade it in completely. This happens randomly....although the overall effect works. Any ideas on why this is happening, or a better way to write this script?

Comment: that did it, make it an answer, and I will accept it...THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using stop(true,true) 
 hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

you can refer this tutorial to know how stop can be use in different ways...[use of stop()](http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/)

the most appropriate way for your condition is ...

```
$(".block").hover(function(){
  $(this).find(".drag").stop(true,true).fadeIn(250);                
}, function(){
  $(this).find(".drag").stop(true,true).fadeOut(250);
});
```

Comment: although your answer is perfectly correct, 3nigma answered it first under the comment, so I have to give it to him. Thanks though!!!